# How to save data with localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing todo-list,  and while it's save  data in `todotask` row and `completed`. inside view
https://jsfiddle.net/6rqfd103/

> I tried to save it as an array, I saved it, but couldn't get it outside and this is the code when I haven't done anything, show me how, I don't understand this place yet. explain to me. thank you very much

```
var newTaskInput = document.getElementById("new-task");
var addButton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
var todoTask = document.getElementById("incomplete-tasks");
var completeTask= document.getElementById("completed-tasks");

var createNewTaskElement = function(taskString) {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var editInput = document.createElement("input");
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  editInput.type = "text";
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";
  editButton.className = "edit";
  deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
  deleteButton.className = "delete";

  label.innerText = taskString;

  listItem.appendChild(checkBox);
  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(editInput);
  listItem.appendChild(editButton);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

  return listItem;
}

var addTask = function() {
    if(newTaskInput.value == ""){
        alert("Nhap todoTask Item !");
        return false;
    }
  var listItem = createNewTaskElement(newTaskInput.value);
  todoTask.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

    newTaskInput.value = "";
    return true;
}

var editTask = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var editInput = listItem.querySelector("input[type=text");
  var label = listItem.querySelector("label");
    var containsClass = listItem.classList.contains("editMode");

  if(containsClass) {
    label.innerText = editInput.value;
  } else {
    editInput.value = label.innerText;
  }
  listItem.classList.toggle("editMode");  
}

var deleteTask = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var ul = listItem.parentNode;

  ul.removeChild(listItem);
}

var taskCompleted = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  completeTask.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskIncomplete);
}

var taskIncomplete = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  todoTask.appendChild(listItem);
  bindTaskEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
}

var bindTaskEvents = function(taskListItem, checkBoxEventHandler) {
  console.log("Bind list item events");
  var checkBox = taskListItem.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
  var editButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.edit");
  var deleteButton = taskListItem.querySelector("button.delete");

  editButton.onclick = editTask;

  deleteButton.onclick = deleteTask;

  checkBox.onchange = checkBoxEventHandler;
}

addButton.addEventListener("click", addTask);

for(var i = 0; i < todoTask.children.length; i++) {
  bindTaskEvents(todoTask.children[i], taskCompleted);
}

for(var i = 0; i < completeTask.children.length; i++) {
  bindTaskEvents(completeTask.children[i], taskIncomplete);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing / using Google Chrome you can use localStorage.setItem() and localStorage.getItem().  The .setItem() creates an object saved to your local storage.  The method takes two arguments, the first is the name of your object (choose whatever name you want) in string format, the second is the value to go inside of the object.  You mentioned you're working with an array as your returned item, the .setItem() 2nd argument can take an array.  One nuance, the data has to be in JSON format.  Example below.

```
const myArray = [1, 2, 3];
const myArrayToJson = JSON.stringify(myArray);
localStorage.setItem('myObjectName', myArrayToJson);
```

Now, when you refresh your page, wherever in your code you're rendering your application to the webpage, you'll want to use the .getItem method, which takes one argument.  That argument is the name of the object you created above.  Then you parse the data and call it or render it wherever you wanted.

```
const myFetchedArrayInJson = localStorage.getItem('myObjectName');
const myFetchedArrayParsed = JSON.parse(myFetchedArrayInJson);
--- Now do something with it.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you help me with this?
Above is the html.